# Godot 4.0. how stop a auto call SceneTreeTimer?

Tags: timer, godot, gdscript

I have this code :

```
extends Area2D

func _ready() -> void : auto_call()
    
func auto_call() : 
    await get_tree().create_timer(1, false).timeout
    print( "area autocall" )
    auto_call()

func stop_auto_call() : 
    auto_call = null # how stop?
```

I know, I can use two options : create a normal `Timer` or save the references in a global array to later stop it/them, but... it could take **a lot** of refactoring in several nodes.

I'm tring *desactive* or *pause* the node and the code works... less the auto_call calls.
I try using `unreference()`, `null`, stoping : `process`, `input` and `physics`. But nothing. I see a little hope with `get_tree().get_processed_tweens()` but it see than don't exist any for `SceneTreeTimer`. Anyone knows what to do, alternatives or ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Godot has a pause system. You can pause the [`SceneTree`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_scenetree.html) by setting its [`paused`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_scenetree.html#class-scenetree-property-paused) to `true`:

```
get_tree().paused = true
```

Which scripts will execute when paused or not depends on [`process_mode`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_node.html#class-node-property-process-mode).

Furthermore, any [`SceneTreeTimer`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_scenetreetimer.html) created with `always_process` set to `false` (which you specify as second argument of [`create_timer`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_scenetree.html#class-scenetree-method-create-timer)), will not run while the scene tree is paused.

*However, this approach will also affect anything else working the pause system and does not give you the granularity of pausing only some of these timers.*

---

You could also use [`Timer`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_timer.html)s:

```
var timer := Timer.new()
add_child(timer)
timer.wait_time = 1.0
timer.one_shot = true
timer.start()
await timer.timeout
timer.queue_free()
```

Or like this:

```
var timer := Timer.new()
add_child(timer)
timer.wait_time = 1.0
timer.one_shot = true
timer.connect("timeout", timer.queue_free, [], CONNECT_ONESHOT)
timer.start()
await timer.timeout
```

Then to pause them, you can get each `Timer` children, that is not queued for deletion, and pause it:

```
for node in get_children():
    var timer:Timer = node as Timer
    if !is_instance_valid(timer) or timer.is_queued_for_deletion():
        continue

    timer.paused = true
```

Note that this will take all children `Timer`s. And that might be more than you want to.

This will allow you to only pause the timers of a specific `Node`.

---

We can create an [Autoload](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/tutorials/scripting/singletons_autoload.html). I'll call it `TimerRoot`. With a script with similar code as described above:

```
extends Node

func delay(wait_time:float) -> void:
    var timer := Timer.new()
    add_child(timer)
    timer.wait_time = 1.0
    timer.one_shot = true
    timer.start()
    await timer.timeout
    timer.queue_free()

func set_paused(pause:bool) -> void:
    for node in get_children():
        var timer:Timer = node as Timer
        if !is_instance_valid(timer) or timer.is_queued_for_deletion():
            continue

        timer.paused = pause
```

Which you can the use like this `await TimerRoot.delay(1.0)` and pause them all like this `TimerRoot.set_paused(true)`.

---

Alternatively you can return the `Timer`:

```
func delay(wait_time:float) -> Timer:
    var timer := Timer.new()
    add_child(timer)
    timer.wait_time = 1.0
    timer.one_shot = true
    timer.connect("timeout", timer.queue_free, [], CONNECT_ONESHOT)
    timer.start()
    return Timer
```

And use it like this: `await TimerRoot.delay(1.0).timeout`.

---

*Another variant is to add a `parent` parameter, and have `delay` add the timer as a child to it. Which gives you back the granularity of pausing only the `Timer`s of a `Node`.*

---

By the way, in this code we are pausing. You could implement a cancel mechanism, where you could add an `if` where you call `delay` to check if it was cancelled. If you are returning the `Timer`, you could have a script attached (which also helps us identify which are the correct timers) with a `cancelled` property. This suggest us to change from an Autoload, to a class:

```
class_name OneShotTimer extends Timer

@export
var cancelled:bool:
    get: return cancelled
    set(mod_value):
        if mod_value and not cancelled:
            cancelled = true
            emit_signal("timeout")

func _ready() -> void:
    one_shot = true
    connect("timeout", queue_free, [], CONNECT_ONESHOT)
    start()

static func delay(parent:Node, time:float) -> bool:
    if !is_instance_valid(parent):
        push_error("Parent Node is not valid.")

    if !parent.is_inside_tree():
        push_error("Parent Node is not in the scene tree.")

    var timer := OneShotTimer.new()
    timer.wait_time = time
    parent.add_child(timer)
    await timer.timeout
    return !timer.cancelled

static func set_paused(parent:Node, pause:bool) -> void:
    for node in parent:
        var timer:OneShotTimer = node as OneShotTimer
        if !is_instance_valid(timer) or timer.is_queued_for_deletion():
            continue
        
        timer.paused = pause

static func cancel(parent:Node) -> void:
    for node in parent:
        var timer:OneShotTimer = node as OneShotTimer
        if !is_instance_valid(timer) or timer.is_queued_for_deletion():
            continue
        
        timer.cancelled = true
```

Which you can use like this:

```
if await OneShotTimer.delay(self, 1.0):
    print("OK")
else:
    print("Aborted operation")
```

And pause all the timers of a node like this `OneShotTimer.set_paused(self, true)`. And to cancel them you do `OneShotTimer.cancel(self)`

If you want both the granularity but also the ability to globally pause or cancel them all, we can bring back the Autoload `TimerRoot` with a different code:

```
extends Node

var _timers:Array

func register(timer:OneShotTimer) -> void:
    if is_instance_valid(timer) and !timer.is_queued_for_deletion():
        _timers.append(timer)
        timer.connect("timeout", func(): _timers.erase(timer), [], CONNECT_ONESHOT)

func cancel() -> void:
    for timer in _timers:
        timer.cancelled = true

func set_paused(pause:bool) -> void:
    for timer in _timers:
        timer.paused = pause
```

Then add `TimerRoot.register(self)` on `_ready` on `OneShotTimer` so they are all registered. And then you can pause all with `TimerRoot.set_paused(true)` or cancel all with `TimerRoot.cancel()`.

---

But that is cancel. Which is not really stopping. Stopping is an issue, because you have some code awaiting for it. If you are Ok with them waiting indefinitely for the signal, you can simply remove the timers with `queue_free`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider just using tween? Would be nice if timer had the same capabilities but...

```
extends Node

var _tween: Tween

func _ready() -> void:
    # every 1 second call _auto_call
    _tween = create_tween().set_loops()
    _tween.tween_callback(_auto_call).set_delay(1)
    # cancel after 10 seconds
    await get_tree().create_timer(10).timeout
    _stop_auto_call()

func _auto_call():
    print( "area autocall" )

func _stop_auto_call() :
    _tween.kill()
```